# How to define a command in latex for capitalizing following text?

Tags: capitalization, syntax, layout

In latex there are commands that change the appearance of their argument, e.g. `\textit{foo}`.
Other commands change the appearance of the following text, without requiring an argument, e.g. `\itshape foo`.

The latter form is often used to make global changes to the appearance of document elements, e.g.:

- `every node/.append style={font={\itshape \small}}` in tikz
- `\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\itshape}` in the koma script bundle

For capitalizing words, latex has the commands `\uppercase{foo}` and `\MakeUppercase{foo}`, but since these capitalize only their argument, they cannot be used for customisation of the layout in the same way as `\itshape`.

So how do we get a command that capitalizes text (like `\MakeUppercase`), but that works syntactically like `\itshape`, so that it can be used for layout customisation in the same way?

Comment: This is not really possible unless you have an all-caps font (which is a theoretical possibility but not that common)

Comment: hmm, that's it pitty, it would be nice if all-caps could be used in a uniform manner alongside other layout options..
Is it not possible to trick LaTeX in using a font as if it were all caps?

Comment: no you could make a virtual or real font that was all caps, in luatex you can do that on the fly in Lua code but it's quite a lot of work, opentype fonts have lots of characters affected by this and you have to re-adjust all the kerning and ligature pairs, probably moving any pairs specified for the uppercase slots to the lowercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I will feel less silly while using caps lock to achieve this effect ;)